# Using android Hilt in a Library (aar)

Tags: android, android-library, aar, dagger-hilt

I created a library using Hilt. it is working fine in standalone app, but when I tried to integrate in a client app, it start giving Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application. Did you forget to specify your Application's class name in your manifest's <application />'s android:name attribute?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3516)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3668)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
```

Probably it asking client app to be implement using Hilt , but my concern is below:

1. I don't want client to know anything about Hilt,
2. I can not ask client to integrate Hilt

Is Hilt is yet to support in AAR files. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. As the stacktrace specifies

> Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application

Hilt needs the `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation on the application class to start generating his injecting code. Without it and without importing Hilt too as a project dependency the injection simply doesn't start.
**Using hilt in a library is not a good practice** as you should either handle the case where hilt is not supported or force your library users to change their architecture to fit your library.

Here's some feedback about this topic.
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2132#issuecomment-704546736